# How to use distinct and sum both together in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, distinct

For example my table contains the following data:

```
ID    price    
-------------
 1     10      
 1     10 
 1     20     
 2     20      
 2     20      
 3     30
 3     30
 4     5
 4     5
 4     15
```

So given the example above,

```
ID    price    
-------------
 1     30          
 2     20           
 3     30
 4     20
-----------
ID     100
```

How to write query in oracle? first sum(distinct price) group by id then sum(all price).

Answer (score 4):

I would be very careful with a data structure like this.  First, check that all `id`s have exactly one price:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having count(distinct price) > 1;
```

I think the safest method is to extract a particular price for each `id` (say the maximum) and then do the aggregation:

```
select sum(price)
from (select id, max(price) as price
      from table t
      group by id
     ) t;
```

Then, go fix your data so you don't have a repeated additive dimension.  There should be a table with one row per id and price (or perhaps with duplicates but controlled by effective and end dates).

The data is messed up; you should not assume that the price is the same on all rows for a given id.  You need to check that every time you use the fields, until you fix the data.

Answer (score 1):

> first sum(distinct price) group by id then sum(all price)

Looking at your **desired output**, it seems you also need the final sum(similar to ROLLUP), however, **ROLLUP** won't directly work in your case.

If you want to **format** your output in exactly the way you have posted your desired output, i.e. with a **header** for the last row of total sum, then you could set the **PAGESIZE** in **SQL*Plus**.

- Using **UNION ALL**

For example,

```
SQL> set pagesize 7
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT ID, SUM(DISTINCT price) AS price
  3  FROM t
  4  GROUP BY id
  5  )
  6  SELECT to_char(ID) id, price FROM DATA
  7  UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'ID' id, sum(price) FROM DATA
  9  ORDER BY ID
 10  /

ID       PRICE
--- ----------
1           30
2           20
3           30
4           20

ID       PRICE
--- ----------
ID         100

SQL>
```

So, you have an additional row in the end with the **total SUM** of price.

- Using **ROLLUP**

Alternatively, you could use **ROLLUP** to get the total sum as follows:

```
SQL> set pagesize 7
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT ID, SUM(DISTINCT price) AS price FROM t GROUP BY id
  3    )
  4  SELECT ID, SUM(price) price
  5  FROM DATA
  6  GROUP BY ROLLUP(id);

        ID      PRICE
---------- ----------
         1         30
         2         20
         3         30
         4         20

        ID      PRICE
---------- ----------
                  100

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,SUM(price) as price
FROM
(SELECT ID,price
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY ID,price) as T
 GROUP BY ID
```

**Explanation:**

The inner query will select different prices for each ids.

i.e.,

```
ID    price    
-------------     
 1     10 
 1     20     
 2     20      
 3     30
 4     5
 4     15
```

Then the outer query will select `SUM` of those prices for each id.

**Final Result :**

```
ID  price
----------
1   30
2   20
3   30
4   20
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e6cb/1).

Comment: Why would you say "first select the distinct prices" and then use group by to do that? Using distinct in the subquery would make things a lot clearer!

Comment: @Boneist: I know it would. I am giving an explanation for what my query does.

Comment: I would suggest you amend your answer. I don't understand why, given the choice of a clear, self-documenting way of doing something, you would pick the one that is less clear and open to misinterpretation!

Comment: @Boneist: Updated my answer with explanation.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. Why are you using group by to do the distinct, when you're not doing any aggregation? Why not just use distinct? eg. `select distinct id, price from tablename`

Answer (score 0):

First do the DISTINCT and then a ROLLUP

```
SELECT ID, SUM(price)        -- sum of the distinct prices
FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT ID, price -- distinct prices per ID
   FROM tab
 ) dt
GROUP BY ROLLUP(ID)          -- two levels of aggregation, per ID and total sum
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1db8/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE ( ID, price ) AS
          SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 30 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 30 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,  5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,  5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 15 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COALESCE( TO_CHAR(ID), 'ID' ) AS ID,
       SUM( PRICE ) AS PRICE
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, PRICE FROM MYTABLE )
GROUP BY ROLLUP ( ID )
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1db8/1/0)**:

```
| ID | PRICE |
|----|-------|
|  1 |    30 |
|  2 |    20 |
|  3 |    30 |
|  4 |    20 |
| ID |   100 |
```